# custom URL protocol for Cocoa Mac with Qt

Tags: cocoa, qt, macos, custom-url

I'm trying to use a custom URL protocol to launch my Qt (4.7.3) application. I've already got it working for Windows, so now it is time for the Mac.

I've already done the necessary changes to the Info.plist, and have the application being launched when one enters 'customrprotocol://etc' in a browser. The problem is that I need some way of passing that entire URL into my application so I can process the arguments (only at the beginning of the application). At this stage no extra argument (argv[1]) is found like in Windows, despite typing out long URLs with my custom URL protocol.

At the moment, I've investigated two potential ways to do this:

1) Make an apple script that I turn into an application bundle whose .plist I modify to respond to customprotocol://, and have that simply launch my real application with 'do shell script' and pass in the URL as an argument. http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/index.html explains this process.

Not sure if I like this option, since you essentially have 2 application bundles at that point and I don't want to have to put two different applications on someone's Mac for this to work. I'm experimenting with putting one bundle in another to see if it works.

2) Handle the actual 'geturl' AppleEvent by incorporating objective-c into my project, which I've tried to do by following this example: [URL scheme - Qt and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561661/url-scheme-qt-and-mac/6699518#6699518).

My problem with this option is that I'm not quite sure how to go about it; I've thrown all the objective-c code into a .mm file that I bring into the project with an OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += objectivecstuff.mm, and I make sure to include the Cocoa framework as a library as well.

Everything compiles fine, but it simply doesn't do what I want it to do (I additionally try to throw the URL into a global variable in the linked example's 'handleGetURLEvent' method so I can process it in a different module).

I think the crux of the problem is that I don't understand the objective-c in that .mm file and am not sure if I need to somewhere instantiate this EventHandler object or whatever. I've tried reading through http://el-tramo.be/blog/mixing-cocoa-and-qt but this guy's example of integrating Cocoa into Qt looks far more C++-oriented then what appears to be the necessary stuff found in [URL scheme - Qt and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561661/url-scheme-qt-and-mac/6699518#6699518), so I'm not sure how to proceed with this option.

Would really appreciate some advice and suggestions at this point!

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

In order to process URLs through Apple Events with Cocoa, you need a few things:

- You need to register your protocol in `Info.plist` using `CFBundleURLTypes`. This is how you tell Launch Services that your application is capable of handling a given scheme. Launch Services looks through all the applications on the system, reading their `Info.plist` files, and creates a big database of them. You can see how you look to LS by running

  ```
  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump
  ```

  (Sorry its path is so long; it just is.) You can use `lsregister` to re-register your app if you need to, but it'll generally do it automatically.
- Since you're using Qt, I don't believe you have an `NSApplication`, so there's not a hook to run the code you're providing. That's ok. You really just wanted to respond to the Apple Event, not run Cocoa. Nokia includes [docs on that](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq12-mac-events.html). Hopefully `QFileOpenEvent` will meet your need without having to use Carbon, but if you do, this part of Carbon is fine (it's not deprecated like other parts of Carbon are). The upside of using Carbon or `QFileOpenEvent` is that you can do all your work in C.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your quick response. I previously found the document you linked to but figured since it was Carbon it wouldn't apply to my situation, so I appreciate you informing me otherwise. At the moment I've gotten my 1st method to work for the 10.6 by including the secondary script-as-application-bundle into my application bundle, which works nicely. I'll come back to try to make this method work when I have some free time. Thank you.