# How to get the source QString instance from a QUrl instance which is invalid?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, qt5

I have constructed a **QUrl** instance like below.

[image]

Here is a output from **PyQt4**, actually i use **Qt5**, but it isn't installed on this machine, so it's just a sample code to demonstrate my problem.

In **Qt5**, i want to get the **source** string "test.pro://account=" from the **QUrl** instance, how can i achieve it?

What i have done?

The **QUrl** class have a private class which is named **QUrlPrivate** which contains a struct named **Error**. The **Error** structure contains **QString** source which is actually what i want. But i don't know how to access it usinig public API from **QUrl**.

Thanks for helping.

In addtion:

I use **PyQt5** on **Mac Os**.

I want to handle [Url Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561661/url-scheme-qt-and-mac).

In fact, in this case, **PyQt5** is equal to **Qt5**. You can test using **Qt5**.

**Qt** has source code below, which means it will convert **NSString** to **QString** and convert **QString** to **QUrl** and construct a **QFileOpenEvent** using this **QUrl** instance and send **QApplication** instance the **QFileOpenEvent** instance.

```
- (void)getUrl:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    [event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] ;

    NSString *urlStr = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];

    QWindowSystemInterface::handleFileOpenEvent(QUrl(QCFString::toQString(urlString)));
}
```

In my **PyQt5** app, i have reimplemented **event** method of **QApplication** instance.

```
def event(self, e):
    if e.type() == QEvent.FileOpen:
        print e.url().toString()
```

But i can't get source string "test.pro://account=" from **QUrl**.

This is all the context.

In fact, where i want to do my work is in **event** handler, so i want to get the source string from **QUrl** instance.

Comment: I doubt you can do that…If you are not using real urls, don't use QUrl, but QString only

Comment: In fact, this QUrl instance is constructed by Qt not myself. My app is launched by Url Scheme on Mac Os. In a word, Qt translate a NSString to QString and then QUrl. This is why i need to get the real string.

Comment: `qDebug() << url.errorString();` for your URL prints out: `"Invalid hostname (contains invalid characters); source was \"test.pro://account=\"; scheme = \"test.pro\", host = \"\""`. Looks pretty informative.

Comment: @vahancho Thanks. I know it but don't you think it's a bad programming habit?So i rather not use errorString to get what i want.

Comment: @jiahilegass, I just suggested to print out error message instead of trying to extract the source string out of invalid url. What is bad programming habit here?

Comment: @vahancho I misunderstood you for telling me to use errorString to extract the source string. I think using errorString to get what you want is a bad programming habit here. I need the real source string to do some work but not print out it.

Comment: IMO we need more context. Yes the software you are working on have some bug, but looks like you are trying to fix it in wrong way. Explain full issue, why do you have invalid `QUrl` (this is minimum).

Comment: @MarekR The context is complicated. But i have updated it in a few words.

Comment: There appears to be a bug in Qt. It is claiming that "account=" is an invalid host name, because it contains invalid characters. However, the "=" is merely a *reserved* character, not an invalid one - so Qt should allow it (even if it the standard does not recommend it). Python's RFC1808-compliant parser has no problem with this url: `urlparse('test.pro://account=')` gives `ParseResult(scheme='test.pro', netloc='account=', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')`. The "=" is reserved for use in query strings, but it has no special meaning in domain names.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you.I will try to compile Cocoa extension to give it a solution.